# Request more than 5 native ads in a Recyclerview - Admob

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

My app has a Recyclerview in which I want to place native admob ads. I'm building it based on this [Codelab example](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed/blob/master/android/final/NativeAdvancedRecyclerViewExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/nativeadvancedrecyclerviewexample/MainActivity.java). However the more items I have on my Recyclerview the less often the ads will be displayed on the screen because the Admob documentation says it is possible to request up to 5 ads. Is there any way to make the ads show more often?

Comment: there is no limit on number of ads to be shown on a screen, as long as its not a disallowed implementation. Can you share documentation links which says you can only load 5 ads?

Comment: @AmodGokhale This is the link https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start#loading_ads

Comment: limit is on individdual loadAds method. Not on admob request. So if you want more ads. Simply call loadAds again when adLoader.isLoading() returns you false inside method onNativeAdLoaded. Don't check on count of ads == 5 as each time there is no guarantee on returning 5 ads. It might return fewer as well.

Comment: there is no restriction on total number of native ads one can load as long as this are followed - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6240814?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214